# Loop through cells in column, store specific value in array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Hey I am a trainee as an IT-Specialist and my trainer gave me a task to complete a macro for excel. (I don't know anything about VBA)

I have to check the cells in a column for the value 1. If there is a 1 I need to store that value in a array.

That's what I did till now.

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyArray() As Single

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")


 LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row


    MsgBox LastRow
    MsgBox Join(MyArray)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub createArray(x As Variant)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim tempArray() As String
Dim rowVal As String
Dim MyArray() As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim rang As Range
Dim arrayEntry As String

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
Set rang = sht.Range("A:A") ' // SET RANGE TO LOOK FOR VALUES

LastRow = rang.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

arrayEntry = ""

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value = x Then ' // (i, 1) <---- '1' references column A - 
change to numerical column that you want to loop through
        If arrayEntry = "" Then
            arrayEntry = x
            rowVal = i
        Else
            arrayEntry = arrayEntry & "," & x
            rowVal = rowVal & "," & i
        End If
    End If
Next i
 
tempArray = Split(arrayEntry, ",")

ReDim MyArray(UBound(tempArray))

For j = 0 To UBound(tempArray)
    MyArray(j) = CInt(tempArray(j))
Next j

Erase tempArray

MsgBox LastRow
MsgBox arrayEntry
MsgBox rowVal
MsgBox (UBound(MyArray) + 1)

End Sub
```

I am unsure if you wanted the value '1' in the array or the row it appears on, swap x with i if you wanted the row number.

```
Sub TESTFORMULA()
createArray (1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey I am really thankful for your help! 
but i have a little trouble with compiling the code it says that i have a Run-time error 9
and it highlights this line: 

>ReDim MyArray(UBound(tempArray))